# Jenkins deploying job over ssh

Tags: jenkins

**Problem:**

I'm running a bash script as part of a deployment using the `sshPublisher` build step. Part of the script is to find a process ID using `netstat` (and `grep`/`awk`). When I log onto the VM and manually run the script, kills the process, but through the Jenkins deploy job, it does not

**Jenkins server (VM1):**

```
stage('deploy'){
    sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: 'fdpdeploy', transfers: [sshTransfer(excludes: '', execCommand: './deploy.sh', execTimeout: 120000, flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', remoteDirectory: '', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: 'target', sourceFiles: 'target/fdp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war')], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: false)])           
}
```

**VM2:** This is the script `deploy.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

processId=$(sudo netstat -plten | grep 9030 | awk {'print $9}' | awk -F '/' {'print $1'})
echo $processId

kill -9 $processId

sleep 5

echo 'Starting FDP app'

nohup java -jar /data/fdp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war &> /data/logs/FDPBizApp.log &

exit 0
fi
```

Comment: First, it looks like that `fi` hanging on the end of `deploy.sh` needs to be removed (there's no matching `if`). I would recommend adding `sudo netstat -plten` above the `processId=$(...)` line so you can see if it's actually identifying the correct process. Also, can you add the output of your build to the end of your question so we can see if provides any insight?

Comment: SSH: Connecting from host [evosedgel009.openstacklocal]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [fdpdeploy] ...
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [./deploy.sh] ...
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
Starting FDP app
SSH: EXEC: completed after 5,204 ms
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [fdpdeploy] ...
SSH: Transferred 1 file(s)

Comment: working fine after commenting out requiretty  in visudo

Answer (score 1):

From the output you posted in the comment, this is the problem:

> `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

#### Option 1 - visudo solution

(This is the solution from the OP):

Use `visudo` to edit the `sudoers` file and comment out the `requiretty` entry

#### Option 2 - Jenkins plugin solution

The Publish Over SSH plugin's [features](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh#PublishOverSSHPlugin-Features) list has the following item:

> Enable the command/script to be executed in a pseudo TTY

You can enable this by adding `usePty: true` to the `sshTransfer` block of your publisher. Your `Jenkinsfile` step should look like this:

```
stage('deploy'){
    sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: 'fdpdeploy', transfers: [sshTransfer(excludes: '', execCommand: './deploy.sh', execTimeout: 120000, flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', remoteDirectory: '', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: 'target', sourceFiles: 'target/fdp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war', usePty: true)], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: false)])           
}
```

The only change from your existing step is to add `, usePty: true` after `sourceFiles:`

Comment: I have commented out requiretty and it is working fine